# keyDown doesn't update NSTextView immediately

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, keydown

I have a `keyDown` function in my application that is used to capture input from a `NSTextView` named `textInput`. Some conversions are done with the input which is appended as a `NSAttributedString` back into the `NSTextView`.

This works fine currently, but the problem I have is that the value entered into the textbox on `keyDown` doesn't get added to the `textInput.textStorage?.string`, until another key is pressed.

For example if I enter the text `abcde` and nothing more into `textInput`, and then inside `func keyDown()` I try to access `textInput.textStorage?.string`, it will return `abcd`.

Here is the function without unnecessary parts:

```
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    let bottomBox = textInput.textStorage?.string // This returns one character short of what is actually in the text box

    if let bottomBox = bottomBox {
        var attribute = NSMutableAttributedString(string: bottomBox)

        // Do some stuff here with bottomBox and attribute

        // Clear and set attributed string
        textInput.textStorage?.mutableString.setString("")
        textInput.textStorage?.append(attribute)
    }
}
```

If I were to use `keyUp`, this isn't a problem, although the problem with `keyUp` is that if the user holds down the key, the attributes on the `NSAttributedString` don't get set until the user releases the key.

I though maybe there was a way to programatically release the keyDown event during the `keyDown` function, or generate a keyUp event, but can't seem to find anything.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: "I have a keyDown function in my application"  Where exactly?

Comment: In a view controller that monitors for keyDown events

Comment: Don't use NSEvent.  Use Notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I like to do is to use Cocoa Bindings with a property observer. Set up your properties like so:

```
class MyViewController: NSViewController {
    @objc dynamic var textInput: String {
        didSet { /* put your handler here */ }
    }

    // needed because NSTextView only has an "Attributed String" binding
    @objc private static let keyPathsForValuesAffectingAttributedTextInput: Set<String> = [
        #keyPath(textInput)
    ]
    @objc private var attributedTextInput: NSAttributedString {
        get { return NSAttributedString(string: self.textInput) }
        set { self.textInput = newValue.string }
    }
}
```

Now bind your text view to `attributedTextInput` with the "Continuously Updates Value" check box checked:

[image]

Et voilà, your property will be immediately updated every time you type a character, and your property's `didSet` will immediately be called.